# osticket ticket Strip Quoted Reply

Tags: php, ticket-system, osticket

I am developing a site with **osTicket v1.9.8** ticket system, which works fine, but I would like to know how to accomplish Thread Mail Structure while Agent or admin post a reply back to customer.

i.e When osticket admin post a reply back to customer, the mail should contain the following:

- Reply text
- Original thread message posted by customer (Question).And if there was any conversations made between them. It should be also listed.
  (just Like thread mail structure or similar to support mail replies).

These are the steps that I have done so far:

- I have disabled Strip Quoted Reply check box in
  settings.php(Admin Panel->Settings->Email)
- When admin Post reply to the ticket, the select box for response shows two options 
  1:Original Message- when selected will append only the original thread message posted by customer in reply Textarea box. 
  2:Last Message- when selected will only append the last message in reply Textarea box.

How do I bring entire conversation in Textarea box or in reply mail.

btw,I tried to post question in their forum page. But couldn't find how to post a new one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots to show? that how you required to display ...

Comment: I found these are the two variables used to fetch Original Message,Last Message
But is there any Ticket Thread expansions variables to fetch all the conversations?? Moreover, its only in latest version. I hope this helps to get the picture what I am trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the easiest way would be to change the way that "original message" works. To do that, edit the file at /include/class.thread.php and around line 2513, change this line:

```
         $entry = $this->entries->filter(array(
            'type' => MessageThreadEntry::ENTRY_TYPE,
            'flags__hasbit' => ThreadEntry::FLAG_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE,
            ))
            ->order_by('id')
            ->first();
```

To be this:

```
 $entry = $this->entries->filter(array(
            'type' => MessageThreadEntry::ENTRY_TYPE,
            'flags__hasbit' => ThreadEntry::FLAG_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE,
            ))
            ->order_by('id');
            //->first(); //commenting this line;
```